# Handling Base Class Without Casting in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, design-patterns, casting

I have been stuck on this problem for two weeks now, any help would mean a lot.

Suppose I have a base class called `request` and another called `reply`:

```
class request
{
public:
    virtual ~request() = default;
    request() = default;
};

class reply
{
public:
    virtual ~reply() = default;
    reply() = default;
};
```

Now I have two classes inheriting from `request`:

```
class temperature_request : public request
{
public:
    temperature_request() = default;
};

class tweets_request : public request
{
public:
    tweets_request() = default;
};
```

Each request has its own type inheriting from `reply`:

```
class temperature_reply : public reply
{
public:
    temperature_reply() = default;
};

class tweets_reply : public reply
{
public:
    tweets_reply() = default;
};
```

I have another class called `replier` that distributes the requests on the APIs and caches the responses from the API, the API inherit from class api:

```
class api
{
public:
    virtual ~API() = default;
    virtual reply* get_reply( request* req) const = 0;
}

class temperature_api : public api
{
    virtual reply* get_reply( request* req) const override
    {
         temperature_request* req_casted = static_cast<temperature_request*>(req);
         const std::string& units = req_casted->units();
         temperature_reply* rep = new temperature_reply(20, req);
         return temperature_reply;
    }
}

class tweets_api : public api
{
    virtual reply* get_reply( request* req) const override
    {
         tweet_request* req_casted = static_cast<tweets_request*>(req);
         const std::string& user = req_casted->user();
         const std::string msg = "This is too much code"
         const std::size_t followers = 9028923;
         tweet_reply* rep = new tweet(msg, followers, req);
         return tweet_reply;
    }
}

class replier
{
public:
    virtual ~replier() = default;
    replier() = default;

    reply* get_reply(const request* req) 
    {    
         const std::string source = req->source_api();
         if(source == "temperature_api")
             return m_temperature_api->get_reply(req);
         if(source == "tweets_api")
             return m_tweets_api->get_reply(req);
         throw("nan");
    };

private:
    std::vector<request*> m_already_requested;
    std::vector<reply*>   m_already_replied;
    temperature_api*      m_temperature_api; //suppose initialized
    tweets_api*           m_tweets_api; //suppose initialized
};
```

Now even to use this I have to cast:

```
const std::string user = "XYZ ABC"
tweets_request* req = new tweets_request(user);
reply* rep = replier->get_reply(req);
tweets_reply* real_rep = static_cast<tweets_reply*>(rep);
const std::string msg = real_rep->message();
```

I am using shared pointers, so don't worry about memory leaks and all other implementation problems, please focus on casting and design :).

My problem is that, with this design, I will be **casting all over the place**, any `reply` should be casted to the correct type (`temperature_reply` or `tweets_reply`) in order to process it further (as in my last example), depending on the `request` type given to `replier::get_reply()`, which I cache (not impelemented for now).

I personally hate casting (my opinion), so please, could you help me **redesign** this so I have no casting, and support caching?

Please, I am stuck on this, I feel that inheritance go hand in hand with casting at this time, which I hope is not true. Could you please, please help?

Comment: What you probably want to do is have the base classes, request and reply, expose a virtual interface that will be implemented by the derived classes. For example `virtual result_code parse_request(/* some parameters here */) = 0;`. The derived classes then define `result_code parse_request(/* same parameters here */) override;`  and implement the method to do whatever specialized behaviours are required. Now no casting is required because at the caller you have something that looks like `result_code result = request_msg->parse_request(/* arguments matching parameters */);` and Bob's yer uncle.

Comment: Other than the claim of smart pointer usage, and the complete and utter lack of said-same in the contrived pseudo example. I don't see the problem, mainly because *nowhere* in the post is there any demonstration of how/where/why a cast is mandatory. The probability that this is an XY problem (e.g. "how do I fix the problem in my solution" vs. "how do I solve the actual problem my solution is trying to solve") is likely also pretty high. How does polymorphism *not* address whatever issues you're talking about?

Comment: @WhozCraig How does polymorphism not address whatever issues you're talking about? Other than what user4581301 mentioned (Which I am trying to understand) I am not using polymorphism anywhere, this is why polymorphism does not address the issue. Casting is clearly needed after getting the reply so I can process it further.

Comment: As @user4581301 stated, this is absolutely the time for the base classes to define virtual methods, and your reply type stuff should inherit from a common type. Then no casting should be required.

Comment: Vero, if the classes are similar enough for inheritance to make sense at all, there will be a way to define a common interface used by all of the derived classes. Once you have that interface sorted out, everyone uses that interface. You might have a few unused parameters in some of the cases, but the magic of virtual functions sorts out the rest of the details and ensures the correct function is called for whatever class is hiding behind the base class.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry I feel stupid not understanding what you responded, I am still reading your answers!

Comment: This isn't stupidity. It seems more a simple case of ignorance. You're missing a piece of information somewhere. If you go back an reread the sections on inheritance and polymorphism in your C++ text you'll find simple examples of what I am trying to explain. Once you understand Polymporphism you'll either see that I'm right or you'll realize that polymorphism is the wrong solution. For all we know you might just need a table of pointers to handler functions and `std::function` is a much better fit.

Comment: In updated question, cast is inevitable since you don't know the type until runtime checked. However if you just want to get rid of cumbersome casts, then you may use CRTP to make an `getDerivedType` to reduce the code.

Comment: I can not understand what you really want to do.
Why these base classes neened?
When you remove all inheritance from your code and simply overload the method `replier::get_reply` for each request types, what problem occur?

Comment: @fana I thought about that too, I need caching and also I want to add some logic to my code. The goal is: 1. Send request of type reqX 2. Distribute the request to the appropriate API 3. Construct a reply 4. Cache the reply for next times and return the reply. If anyone has an idea on how to this even if it’s complex or templated I am ready to use it.

Comment: I think all the problem would be solved if you're using `std::variant` (or boost version). It's what you need for a heterogeneous cache.

Comment: Do you really need to adopt the implementation of "cache different types in a single vector"? I can't understand why you desire this implementation shape.
Other implementations are wrong? For example, "prepare vector for each type" or "X_request has a member variable X_reply (as a cache of reply)" or etc...

Answer (score 2):

The crux of the problem is that you are simply not utilizing polymorphism to its full potential.  Yes, you have virtual destructors, good for you.  That is important.  But, you are not using virtual methods to tie your related classes together in a polymorphic way.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
class reply;

class request
{
public:
    request() = default;
    virtual ~request() = default;

    virtual std::shared_ptr<reply> create_reply() = 0;
};

class reply
{
public:
    reply() = default;
    virtual ~reply() = default;
};
```

```cpp
class reply_type_one : public reply
{
public:
    reply_type_one() = default;
};

class request_type_one : public request
{
public:
    request_type_one() = default;

    std::shared_ptr<reply> create_reply() override {
        return std::make_shared<reply_type_one>();
    }
};

class reply_type_two : public reply
{
public:
    reply_type_two() = default;
};

class request_type_two : public request
{
public:
    request_type_two() = default;

    std::shared_ptr<reply> create_reply() override {
        return std::make_shared<reply_type_two>();
    }
};
```

```cpp
class replier
{
public:
    replier() = default;
    virtual ~replier() = default;

    std::shared_ptr<reply> get_reply(const std::shared_ptr<request> &req) 
    { 
        auto iter = std::find(m_already_requested.begin(), m_already_requested.end(), req);
        if (iter != m_already_requested.end())
            return *iter;

        auto reply = req->create_reply();
        m_already_requested.push_back(req);
        m_already_replied.push_back(reply);
        return reply;
    }

private:
    std::vector<shared_ptr<request>> m_already_requested;
    std::vector<shared_ptr<reply>> m_already_replied;
};
```

Though, in the latter case, a `std::unordered_map` would make more sense than 2 `std::vector`s:

```cpp
class replier
{
public:
    replier() = default;
    virtual ~replier() = default;

    std::shared_ptr<reply> get_reply(const std::shared_ptr<request> &req) 
    { 
        auto iter = m_cache.find(req);
        if (iter == m_cache.end())
        {
            auto reply = req->create_reply();
            iter = m_cache.insert(std::make_pair(req, reply)).first;
        }
        return *iter;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::shared_ptr<request>, std::shared_ptr<reply>> m_cache;
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time :). I am starting to doubt if I asked the question clearly. The reply class is just a container of some data e.g. reply_1 could be of type tweet so contains account info, and the tweet msg as a string and reply_2 could be the weather (temperature), the APIs that I didn't put in my example will populate the reply, so I have to: 1. take a request 2. dispatch the request and send it to the right API 3. Populate the appropriate reply 4. send the reply and cache it (caching is same as in code). I can't create_reply() from nothing, I have to go through APIs.

Comment: What I said here: 

    reply* get_reply(const request* req) 

    { 

         check_cash(req) otherwise create a reply from scratch; 

    };

Is tricky: "otherwise create a reply from scratch" means send the request to the right API and get the response and cache it :)

Comment: @Vero You should provide the code related to your comments above by [edit] your question. I think that's the real question. You probably want to get the data in derived class and that's the case you need to case and I think that's the common case for cast.

Comment: ok will do asap

Comment: @Vero, note that the code must include *where you cast* which isn't depicted in your original question.

Comment: Have updated and showed all the ugly casts :)

Answer (score 0):

Cast is inevitable since you don't know the type until runtime.

However if you just want to get rid of cumbersome casts, then you may use CRTP to make an `getDerivedType()` to reduce the code.

At least you don't have to code the `static_cast()` part when you need to create another derived class.

Note: CRTP bloats the code. If possible, I suggest to use a simple helper class to *append* this helper function instead of adding it to your original `Base` class.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/774hWW6ba)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class BaseReq{

};
class TweetReq: public BaseReq{
public:
    int getFollowers(){
        return 42;
    }
};

template<typename DerivedReply>
class BaseReplier{
public:
    virtual std::string somework(BaseReq* req) = 0;
protected:
    DerivedReply* getDerivedReq( BaseReq* reply ){
        return static_cast<DerivedReply*>(reply);
    }
};


class TweetReplier: public BaseReplier<TweetReq>{ // <--- inject the derived request type you want to cast.
public:
    std::string somework(BaseReq* req) override {
        int followers = getDerivedReq(req)->getFollowers();
        return std::to_string(followers);
    }
};

int main()  
{
    TweetReq req;
    TweetReplier replier;
    std::cout << replier.somework(&req) << "\n";
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If downcast are inevitable it's a bad design. That need shows the interface it does not suite well for what is he doing. To be clear I agree with your solution but not with your first statement.

Comment: @Moia, could you provide a design not requiring downcast? I'd like to know how would you tackle this issue. Probably I missed a design pattern which is essential for this question.

Comment: Note that replies are cached in a vector of reply*, surely they have to  be casted in order to be used later. Would PImpl design work here, I thought about it but even if I have only one class Request and Reply with there imp inside, I need to cast these imp pointers to work with them, same as the current problem. For CRTP I thought about it too, but I need to cache, hence vector wouldn’t work as template are different, also CRTP doesn’t work because if I inherit A from B<A> and later inherit C from A how can It work? It’s recursive ugly code again.

Comment: @Vero 1. I believe `replier` should have flat inheritance hierarchy which contains 1~3 inheritance. 2. This CRTP technique should be used on the most derived class. 3. Probably don't use 3. What fana suggested in the comment of the question might be valueable.